# Why data is not transmitting

Tags: c++, boost-asio

I am trying to designed a client server program in which both party {server, client } can communicate with async_connect. 
this is my server program code:

```
std::string GetMessage()
{
    std::string user("User");
    user += client;
    client++;
    return user;

}

class TcpConnection
        : public boost::enable_shared_from_this<TcpConnection>
{
private:
    boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket socket1;
    std::string message;


    TcpConnection(boost::asio::io_service &io_service) :
            socket1(io_service)
    {
    }

    void Writehandler(const boost::system::error_code &errorCode, size_t size)
    {
        if (!errorCode)
        {
            Read();
        }
        std::cout << errorCode.message() << std::endl;
    }

public:
    typedef boost::shared_ptr<TcpConnection> pointer;

    static pointer Create(boost::asio::io_service &io_service)
    {
        return pointer(new TcpConnection(io_service));
    }

    boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket &socket()
    {
        return socket1;
    }

    void Start()
    {
        message = GetMessage();
        boost::asio::async_write(socket(), boost::asio::buffer(message),
                                 boost::bind(&TcpConnection::Writehandler, shared_from_this(),
                                             boost::asio::placeholders::error,
                                             boost::asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred));
    }

    void Read()
    {
        std::array<char, 65> messages{};
        auto self(shared_from_this());
        boost::asio::async_read(socket(),
                                boost::asio::buffer(messages),
                                [this, self](boost::system::error_code ec, std::size_t /*length*/) {
                                    if (!ec) {
                                        Read();
                                    } else {
                                       std::cout << ec.message() << std::endl;
                                        exit(1);
                                    }
                                });
    }

};

class Server
{
private:
    boost::asio::ip::tcp::acceptor acceptor;


public:
    Server(boost::asio::io_service &io_service, unsigned short int port)
            :
            acceptor(io_service, boost::asio::ip::tcp::endpoint(boost::asio::ip::tcp::v4(), port))
    {
        startAccept();
    }

    void startAccept()
    {
        TcpConnection::pointer newConnection = TcpConnection::Create(acceptor.get_io_service());
        acceptor.async_accept(newConnection->socket(),
                              boost::bind(&Server::Handler, this, newConnection, boost::asio::placeholders::error
                              ));
    }

    void Handler(TcpConnection::pointer &newConnection, const boost::system::error_code &errorCode)
    {
        if (!errorCode)
            newConnection->Start();
        startAccept();
    }
};
```

}

and this is my client code:

```
 class Client
            : public boost::enable_shared_from_this<Client>
    {
    private:
        boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket socket1;
        std::string port;

    public:
        Client(boost::asio::io_service &io_service, std::string port)
                : port(std::move(port)),
                  socket1(io_service)
        {
            start();
        }

        void handler(const boost::system::error_code &errorCode, size_t size)
        {
        }

        boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket &socket()
        {
            return socket1;
        }

        void start()
        {
            try
            {
                boost::asio::ip::tcp::resolver resolver(socket1.get_io_service());
                boost::asio::ip::tcp::resolver::query query(boost::asio::ip::tcp::v4(), port);
                boost::asio::ip::tcp::resolver::iterator endpoint = resolver.resolve(query);

               std::cout << exception.what() << std::endl;
            }
        }

        void read()
        {
            std::array<char, 64> messages{};
            boost::asio::async_read(socket(),
                                    boost::asio::buffer(messages.data(), messages.size()),
                                    [this](boost::system::error_code ec, std::size_t /*length*/)
                                    {
                                        if (!ec)
                                        {
                                            read();
                                        } else
                                        {
                                            socket().close();
                                        }
                                    });
        }

        void write()
        {
            std::string message{};
            getline(std::cin, message, '\n');
            boost::asio::async_write(socket(),
                                     boost::asio::buffer(message),
                                     [this](boost::system::error_code ec, std::size_t /*length*/)
                                     {
                                         if (!ec)
                                         {
                                             write();

                                         } else
                                         {
                                             socket().close();
                                         }
                                     });
        }

    };
```

The code is error free. but when i connected both data in not injecting.

Comment: `The code is error free.` Where do you actually use [`boost::asio::connect`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_64_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/connect.html) or [`boost::asio::async_connect`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_64_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/async_connect.html) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `Client::start` function you never actually connect to any remote server. You only resolve the address of the remote partner.

[`boost::asio::connect`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_64_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/connect.html) or [`boost::asio::async_connect`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_64_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/async_connect.html) might be what you want.

```
void start()
{
    try
    {
        boost::asio::ip::tcp::resolver resolver(socket1.get_io_service());
        boost::asio::ip::tcp::resolver::query query(boost::asio::ip::tcp::v4(), port);
        boost::asio::ip::tcp::resolver::iterator endpoint = resolver.resolve(query);
        boost::asio::connect(socket(), endpoint); //<--- Connect to your server

        std::cout << exception.what() << std::endl;
    }
    catch (const std::exception &e)
    {
        //Handle
    }
    catch (const boost::system::system_error &e)
    {
        //Handle
    }
}
```

You might also want to `catch` something with your try block. I'm not sure which compiler lets you do this.

Also it's recommended to create the read-buffer as a class member.